# Zoom image in/out on mouse point using wheel with transform origin center. Need help in calculation

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

**CONTEXT :**

- My requirement is to do image transformations like scale, rotate and translate with user actions on an image.
- Rotation and translation of image is done in its center using transform origin 50% 50% ( default ).
- For scaling the image on mouse point using mouse wheel, i was able to make it work with transform origin 0 0
- Just to accomodate the scale behaviour if i change the origin, i am required to recalculate other transformations relative to the new origin.

**PROBLEM :**

- How to scale the image on mouse point if the transform origin is defaulted to 50% 50% by default ?
- The following fiddle works with transform origin 0 0 for reference. I needhelp in optimizing this calculations using transform origin 50% 50%.

Can someone assist in optimizing this calculation further so that it works with default transform origin ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .container {
      background-color: lightgrey;
      }
      .stage {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      }
      #image {
      transform-origin: 0 0;
      height: auto;
      width: 80%;
      cursor: grab;
      }
      .actions {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 1.5rem;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      }
      .action {
      margin-right: 1rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="stage">
        <img id="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832__480.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="action">
          <label for="rotate">Rotate </label>
          <input type="range" id="rotate" name="rotate" min="0" max="360">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const img = document.getElementById('image');
      const rotate = document.getElementById('rotate');
      let mouseX;
      let mouseY;
      let mouseTX;
      let mouseTY;
      let startXOffset = 222.6665;
      let startYOffset = 224.713;
      let startX = 0;
      let startY = 0;
      let panning = false;
      
      const ts = {
        scale: 1,
        rotate: 0,
        translate: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        }
      };
      
      rotate.oninput = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ts.rotate = event.target.value;
        setTransform();
      };
      
      img.onwheel = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let xs = (event.clientX - ts.translate.x) / ts.scale;
        let ys = (event.clientY - ts.translate.y) / ts.scale;
        let delta = (event.wheelDelta ? event.wheelDelta : -event.deltaY);
        ts.scale = (delta > 0) ? (ts.scale * 1.2) : (ts.scale / 1.2);
        ts.translate.x = event.clientX - xs * ts.scale;
        ts.translate.y = event.clientY - ys * ts.scale;
        setTransform();
      };
      
      img.onmousedown = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        panning = true;
        img.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
        mouseTX = ts.translate.x;
        mouseTY = ts.translate.y;
      };
      
      img.onmouseup = function(event) {
        panning = false;
        img.style.cursor = 'grab';
      };
      
      img.onmousemove = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const x = event.clientX;
        const y = event.clientY;
        pointX = (x - startX);
        pointY = (y - startY);
        if (!panning) {
          return;
        }
        ts.translate.x =
          mouseTX + (x - mouseX);
        ts.translate.y =
          mouseTY + (y - mouseY);
        setTransform();
      };
      
      function setTransform() {
        const steps = `translate(${ts.translate.x}px,${ts.translate.y}px) scale(${ts.scale}) rotate(${ts.rotate}deg)`;
        img.style.transform = steps;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand why scaling should involve repositioning - could you explain what you want to achieve here?

Comment: As stated the requirement is to enable zoom in/out using mouse wheel on the mouse point over the image. When we scale an image with a specific origin, the image below the mouse point moves to different location. So to emulate the image scaling over that specific point we need to compensate that with proper translations. If you can check the fiddle you would undertand the behaviour.

Comment: I did check the fiddle but I didn't understand the behavior which is why I asked the question. OK, so the mouse is to stay on the same point of the image, got it. This is where we need a CSS scale prooperty separated out from the rest of transform - coming but not in all browsers yet.

Comment: The scale on mouse point works only when the origin is set to 0 0. But i want the rotation to happen at center of image. So to accomodate everything to a common origin of 50% 50% ( default ), how to change the calculation of "onwheel" callback so that it works as expected ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to scale the image on mouse point if the transform origin is defaulted to 50% 50% by default ?

To shift origin to 50% 50% we need x,y position of mouse, relative to the image i.e. image top left as origin till image bottom right. Then we compensate image position by using the relative coordinates. We need to consider image dimensions as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .container {
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    
    .stage {
      height: 90vh;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #image {
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      height: auto;
      width: 40%;
      cursor: grab;
    }
    
    .actions {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 1.5rem;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    
    .action {
      margin-right: 1rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="stage">
      <img id="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832__480.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="action">
        <label for="rotate">Rotate </label>
        <input type="range" id="rotate" name="rotate" min="0" max="360">
        <button onclick="reset()">Reset All</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const img = document.getElementById('image');
    const rotate = document.getElementById('rotate');
    let mouseX;
    let mouseY;
    let mouseTX;
    let mouseTY;
    let startXOffset = 222.6665;
    let startYOffset = 224.713;
    let startX = 0;
    let startY = 0;
    let panning = false;

    const ts = {
      scale: 1,
      rotate: 0,
      translate: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    };

    rotate.oninput = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      ts.rotate = event.target.value;
      setTransform();
    };

    img.onwheel = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //need more handling  to avoid fast scrolls
      var func = img.onwheel;
      img.onwheel = null;

      let rec = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      let x = (event.clientX - rec.x) / ts.scale;
      let y = (event.clientY - rec.y) / ts.scale;

      let delta = (event.wheelDelta ? event.wheelDelta : -event.deltaY);
      ts.scale = (delta > 0) ? (ts.scale + 0.2) : (ts.scale - 0.2);

      //let m = (ts.scale - 1) / 2;
      let m = (delta > 0) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
      ts.translate.x += (-x * m * 2) + (img.offsetWidth * m);
      ts.translate.y += (-y * m * 2) + (img.offsetHeight * m);

      setTransform();
      img.onwheel = func;
    };

    img.onmousedown = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      panning = true;
      img.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
      mouseX = event.clientX;
      mouseY = event.clientY;
      mouseTX = ts.translate.x;
      mouseTY = ts.translate.y;
    };

    img.onmouseup = function(event) {
      panning = false;
      img.style.cursor = 'grab';
    };

    img.onmousemove = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let rec = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      let xx = event.clientX - rec.x;
      let xy = event.clientY - rec.y;

      const x = event.clientX;
      const y = event.clientY;
      pointX = (x - startX);
      pointY = (y - startY);
      if (!panning) {
        return;
      }
      ts.translate.x =
        mouseTX + (x - mouseX);
      ts.translate.y =
        mouseTY + (y - mouseY);
      setTransform();
    };

    function setTransform() {
      const steps = `translate(${ts.translate.x}px,${ts.translate.y}px) scale(${ts.scale}) rotate(${ts.rotate}deg) translate3d(0,0,0)`;
      //console.log(steps);
      img.style.transform = steps;
    }

    function reset() {
      ts.scale = 1;
      ts.rotate = 0;
      ts.translate = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      rotate.value = 180;
      img.style.transform = 'none';
    }

    setTransform();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To make things simple I am adding 0.2 to the scale instead of multiplying with 1.2. You can change it back with right proportions. Also added a reset button.
Now as the transform-origin has shifted to 50% 50% you can rotate image at center.

Comment: Thank you for the resolution. Much appreciated for your time to solve this.

Comment: Happy to help! I wish devtools had element coordinate indicators. :( Just a thought, if you  can explore possibility of using `transform: translate(10px, 10px) scale(2) translate(-5px, 10px) rotate(30deg);` I don't know how many you can stack at a time. Also, you can set top and left on absolutely positioned image instead of translating(x, y) . I mean use top, left for dragging and translate to compensate for scaling. This may make calculations simple.

Comment: I've initially used `top` `left` for translating elements. But to reduce the number of paint cycles while updating the position and to reach consistent 60 fps when i move the element, i used transforms. Thus reducing recalculations for every mouse event.