# How to understand the running logic of the following code, About transform zoom center

Tags: javascript, html, css

It implements the function of controlling the transformation of child elements on the parent element. I have never been able to write the change of scaling. It seems to me to be very complicated. I originally used transformOrigin but found it too complicated, so I changed it to dynamic during scaling. I couldn't write the transform-late method to modify the image. Fortunately, there are examples for reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70210288/zoom-image-in-out-on-mouse-point-using-wheel-with-transform-origin-center-need). I quickly achieved the effect I wanted, but I couldn't understand his code. I commented on the places I didn't understand. I hope to get Answer, thank you.

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.box');
        let img = document.querySelector('img');
        let dot = document.querySelector('.dot');
        let isDown = false;
        let downx = 0;
        let downy = 0;
        let position = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
        let scale = 1;
        box.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation()
            event.preventDefault()
            let rec = img.getBoundingClientRect();
            //  i don't know why but it works. i think it's the relative position of the mouse on the image?
            //  hope for explanation. why do this
            let x = (event.clientX - rec.x) / scale;
            let y = (event.clientY - rec.y) / scale;
            dot.style.left = x + 'px';
            dot.style.top = y + 'px';
            let delta = (event.wheelDelta ? event.wheelDelta : -event.deltaY);

            let ls = scale // keep last scale   
            scale = (delta > 0) ? (scale + 0.2) : (scale - 0.2);
            if (scale > 3 || scale < 0.8) {
                scale = ls
                return
            }
            /**
             * Here is the second thing I don’t understand. 
             * I probably know that it is to calculate the offset of the image and correct it, but I don’t understand it.
             * Maybe you can draw a diagram to help understand, thank you very much❤️
             **/
            let m = (delta > 0) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
            let x1 = (-x * m * 2) + (img.offsetWidth * m);
            let y1 = (-y * m * 2) + (img.offsetHeight * m);
            position.x += x1
            position.y += y1
            updateTransform()
        }, { passive: false });

        box.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            isDown = true;
            downx = e.clientX - position.x;
            downy = e.clientY - position.y;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            if (isDown) {
                position.x = e.clientX - downx
                position.y = e.clientY - downy
                updateTransform()
            }
        });

        box.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
            isDown = false;
        });

        function updateTransform() {
            img.style.transform = `scale(${scale}) translate(${position.x / scale}px, ${position.y / scale}px)`;
        }
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 50px;
        height: 600px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        user-select: none;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <img src="https://pica.zhimg.com/80/v2-b3fd7b886b18c45a3623b9f13c3372c5_qhd.jpg?source=4e949a73" alt="">
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
```

I don't understand the operation of the code and hope to get answers. I read many articles and asked questions to gpt, but I can't solve my confusion very well.

Comment: Hi what does the last thing you wrote mean? Write everything in english, please.